# Yii alert widget

Tags: php, yii2, yii-widgets

In view I have widget:

```
if ($content):
        echo Alert::widget([
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'alert-info',
            ],
            'body' => $content,
        ]);
endif;
```

That widget I want render not always, for example after save and atc. Now Now I have placed that widget between if condition, maybe exists some more clear way to render widget only in some cases.

Comment: You can use `falsh` instead of this widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Flash-Messages is what you want:

**For Example:**
In the **controller** you can do something like that:

```
<?php
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Data saved!");
$this->redirect(array('thing/view', 'id' => 1));
```

And in the **view**:

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('success')):?>
<div class="info">
    <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And of course you can combine it with the alert-widget or with a custom-widget.

See full documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/